# NSString tests not working while testing if string location is null

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

Okay I know there are like a thousand questions of this type, but none of those suggestions seem to work so I am forced to make yet another question about this since this is starting to break my b**ls. Now the question and context:

I get a location from the iPhone, but in the case that the location is not available or part of it is not available I reinitialize the string to @"" instead of a ugly @"(null)" because this location I get it uploaded into a server.

This is the allocation of the variables:

```
        NSString *country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.country];
        NSString *postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.postalCode];
        NSString *locality = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.locality];
        NSString *thoroughfare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.thoroughfare];
        NSString *subThoroughfare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.subThoroughfare];
```

These are the tests I'm currently making:

```
        if (country == (id)[NSNull null] || country.length == 0) {
            NSLog(@"Entered first if for (null)");
            country = @"";
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (postalCode == (id)[NSNull null] || postalCode.length == 0) {
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (locality == (id)[NSNull null] || locality.length == 0) {
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (thoroughfare == (id)[NSNull null] || thoroughfare.length == 0) {
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (subThoroughfare == (id)[NSNull null] || subThoroughfare.length == 0) {
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        }
```

Second:

```
        if (country == @"(null)") {
            NSLog(@"Entered first if for (null)");
            country = @"";
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (postalCode == @"(null)") {
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (locality == @"(null)") {
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (thoroughfare == @"(null)") {
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (subThoroughfare == @"(null)") {
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        }
```

Third:

```
        if (!country) {
            NSLog(@"Entered first if for (null)");
            country = @"";
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (!postalCode) {
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (!locality) {
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (!thoroughfare) {
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (!subThoroughfare) {
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        }
```

Fourth:

With a class:

```
static inline BOOL IsEmpty(id thing) {
return thing == nil
|| ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
    && [(NSData *)thing length] == 0)
|| ([thing respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
    && [(NSArray *)thing count] == 0);
}
        if (IsEmpty(country)) {
            NSLog(@"Entered first if for (null)");
            country = @"";
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (IsEmpty(postalCode)) {
            postalCode = @"";
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (IsEmpty(locality)) {
            locality = @"";
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (IsEmpty(thoroughfare)) {
            thoroughfare = @"";
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        } else if (IsEmpty(subThoroughfare)) {
            subThoroughfare = @"";
        }
```

So there are two possibilities, I'm making something horribly wrong or there is a much simpler way to do this. I NSLogged the variables to this output:

```
Variables before testing, country: (null)
postalCode: (null)
```

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I also tried to trim the strings to no avail.

Comment: I skimmed over your post but don't see a question.

Comment: Testing for a null string is as simple as `if (!s) ...`. Beyond that, I cannot begin to fathom what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The question is why these tests don't work and how to make them work.

Comment: What if two `NSString` are null ?

Comment: @Marcelo: I already do that test (which does NOT work) and what I'm trying to accomplish is changing the output from "(null)" to "" because this data gets uploaded to a server and then to a user interface, on the user interface a ugly "(null)" gets outputted instead of a "".

Comment: @Joze: That test doesn’t work because you’re converting those properties/struct members to strings with `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, which always returns a string object different from `nil`. But why are you creating those strings with `+stringWithFormat:`?

Comment: @Bavarious. Not really a reason. Just did. But DarkDust's answer works for me. Can you suggest another way?

Comment: @Joze Are those declared properties/struct members strings (`NSString`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question more carefully, I’ve noticed you’re using `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` when assigning the strings to your variables:

```
NSString *country = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.country];
NSString *postalCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.postalCode];
NSString *locality = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.locality];
NSString *thoroughfare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.thoroughfare];
NSString *subThoroughfare = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", placemarkFound.subThoroughfare];
```

This is the reason why a test like

```
if (! country)
```

or

```
if (country == nil)
```

doesn’t work: `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` always returns a non-`nil` string. In your particular code, if `placemarkFound.country == nil`, then your `country` variable contains a string representation of `nil`, namely `(null)`.

Since you’ve said you have no particular reason to use `+stringWithFormat:`, and assuming all properties/struct members are strings, here’s one solution to your problem:

```
NSString *country = @"";
NSString *postalCode = @"";
NSString *locality = @"";
NSString *thoroughfare = @"";
NSString *subThoroughfare = @"";

if (placemarkFound.country) country = placemarkFound.country;
if (placemarkFound.postalCode) postalCode = placemarkFound.postalCode;
if (placemarkFound.locality) locality = placemarkFound.locality;
if (placemarkFound.thoroughfare) thoroughfare = placemarkFound.thoroughfare;
if (placemarkFound.subThoroughfare) subThoroughfare = placemarkFound.subThoroughfare;
```

Note that the variables contain an empty string unless their corresponding properties/struct members are different from `nil`.

There’s a handy shortcut for this situation. Instead of the code above, you can use the following code that employs the ternary conditional operator:

```
NSString *country = (placemarkFound.country ? : @"");
NSString *postalCode = (placemarkFound.postalCode ? : @"");
NSString *locality = (placemarkFound.locality ? : @"");
NSString *thoroughfare = (placemarkFound.thoroughfare ? : @"");
NSString *subThoroughfare = (placemarkFound.subThoroughfare ? : @"");
```

Explaining it:

```
NSString *country = (placemarkFound.country ? : @"");
```

means the following: if `placemarkFound.country` is different from `nil`, assign it to the `country` variable. Otherwise, assign an empty string to the `country` variable.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Everything is much more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `country == @"(null)"` you need to do: `[country isEqual:@"(null)"]` (or `[country isEqualToString:@"(null)"]`). The `==` operator tests for pointer equality, but you want to check for object value equality.

**Edit:**

So, the second way is probably the way to go (with the fixed check), but I'd recommend to reverse the check:

```
if ([@"(null)" isEqual:myStringToTest]) { ... }
```

<strike>This way, the object on which `isEqual:` is called is guaranteed to be always a valid object (the static object representing `@"(null)"`).</strike>

Comment: I don’t understand the reasoning behind sending the message to `@"(null)"`. In what cases do you consider `myStringToTest` not being a ‘valid object’?

Comment: @Bavarious: You're right, it was just wrong thinking regarding defensive programming.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this too... `if(  (NSNull *)country == [NSNull null] )`